# How to connect to postgresql 10+ database with pgAdmin 3?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I know that pgAdmin3 is now obsolete, but I still perfer it to pgAdmin4.
It was working fine up to PostgreSQL 9.* version, but when I try to connect to PostgreSQL 10 database I get:

[image]

Is there any workaround for this, or is this truly the end of pgAdmin III?

Comment: The latest pgAdmin3 does connect to PgSQL 10 just fine for me, it does throw some errors but works. So I don’t know why this happens to you. Have been meaning to set up a compile environment for pgAdmin3 and fix those and release a version for PgSQL 10 but it takes time.

Comment: FWIW I use pgadmin 3 with PG 10 without any problems (after clicking ok to a bunch of errors) when initially connecting to the server. The error you're getting is not one of the ones I get though.

Comment: You should consult the PostgreSQL server log.

Answer (score 5):

The official pgAdmin3 has issues with PgSQL 10 and is no longer being developed, but there is a fork available at https://www.openscg.com/bigsql/pgadmin3/ which does work, and will continue to receive updates.

Comment: Great, just installed it, except that I'm now on 11, and this fork supports only 8-10, but hope they'll catch up.

Comment: The link is not working now. Does anybody know where to get this new fork?
Thanks

Comment: Now it seems to be in the complete package of BIGSQL https://www.bigsql.org/pgadmin3/ ... it can only be installed as standalone on Linux systems (as far as I understand this page)

Comment: [https://www.bigsql.org/pgadmin3/] (https://www.bigsql.org/pgadmin3/) ...Described as: **pgAdmin3 LTS by BigSQL**

Comment: Can't find pgAdmin3 in BigSQL bigsql/apg list... Trying install pgAdmin v1.23.0b but wihtout success.